# Count the number of fingers

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

This is an image of convex hull of hand plus defect points:

[image]

Where:

- Blue circles: start points
- Red circles: end points
- Green circles: depth points.

I want to define the finger counter from defect points. Does any one have any idea to get the number of fingers?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (defectArray[i].depth > ??? )
```

Draw marks for all defects. Count defects

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's clear cut. As far as I can see, assuming you can easily find ROI for the hand, you can easily make it classification problem of 6 (0-5) classes. And then you can train your data with some classification methods such as NN, SVM, and so on.

By adding more segmentation of palm and folded fingers, you will get enough accuracy.